# Problema con el header de un PDF de itextsharp en c#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Tengo un problema al momento de usar el header de un pdf hecho con `itextsharp` ya que se sobreescribe una tabla encima del el (El header es lo que dice "TITULO DEL PDF").

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esto no ocurra?

Adjunto código e imagen:

Lo que está marcado en amarillo es el header y la tabla se pone encima de el:
[image]

```
protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       PDF();
   }

   void PDF()
   {
       PruebaChart_BC lobGrafica = new PruebaChart_BC();
       DataTable dtGrafica = lobGrafica.Grafica();
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       string filename = null;
       Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 20, 20);
       PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
       pw.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
       document.Open();
       PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dtGrafica.Columns.Count);
       BaseFont bff = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1250,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
       Font fontText = new Font(bff,10,0,BaseColor.BLACK);
       Font Columnas = new Font(bff, 9, 1, BaseColor.BLACK);
       PdfContentByte cb = pw.DirectContent;
       table.WidthPercentage = 100f;
       table.TotalWidth = 100f;


       document.Add(new Paragraph("Luis Alberto es el mejor del mundo"));
       document.Add(new Paragraph("Y dani es super gay"));
       document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
       filename = "PdfLuis";
       foreach (DataColumn c in dtGrafica.Columns)
       {
           PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell();
           //table.AddCell(new Paragraph(c.ColumnName, Columnas));
           _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(c.ColumnName, Columnas));
           _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
           _cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.CYAN;
           table.AddCell(_cell);
       }

       foreach (DataRow r in dtGrafica.Rows)
       {
           if (dtGrafica.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell();
               //table.AddCell(new Paragraph(r[0].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(r[0].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
               table.AddCell(_cell);
               //table.AddCell(new Paragraph(r[1].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(r[1].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
               table.AddCell(_cell);
               //table.AddCell(new Paragraph(r[2].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(r[2].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
               table.AddCell(_cell);
               //table.AddCell(new Paragraph(r[3].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(r[3].ToString(), fontText));
               _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
               table.AddCell(_cell);
           }
       }
       //table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 200, 550, cb); 
       document.Add(table);
       document.Close();
       Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=" + filename + ".pdf"));
       Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
   }
   class HeaderFooter : PdfPageEventHelper
   {
       public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
       {


           //tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, page.Left + document.LeftMargin, page.Top, writer.DirectContent);
               //(0,-1,document.LeftMargin, writer,PageSize.GetTop(document.TopMargin) + 40,writer.DirectContent);


           PdfPTable tbFooter = new PdfPTable(3);
           tbFooter.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
           tbFooter.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
           tbFooter.AddCell(new Paragraph());


           PdfPCell _cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("PARTE DE ABAJO"));
           _cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
           _cell2.Border = 0;
           tbFooter.AddCell(_cell2);



           _cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Pagina: " + writer.PageNumber));
           _cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
           _cell2.Border = 0;


           tbFooter.AddCell(_cell2);
          // tbFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (document.PageSize.Height - 50), writer.DirectContent);
           //tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, writer, PageSize, writer.DirectContent);
           //tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
           //tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
           tbFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 10, tbFooter.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
       }
       public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
       {
           PdfPTable tbHeader = new PdfPTable(3);
           tbHeader.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
           tbHeader.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

           tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph());
           PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TITULO DEL PDF"));
           _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
           _cell.Border = 0;
           tbHeader.AddCell(_cell);
           tbHeader.AddCell(new Paragraph());
           tbHeader.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 150, document.Top, writer.DirectContent);
           //(0, -1, 10, tbFooter.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas haciendo es asignar a una celda un párrafo, osea el valor del string "TITULO DEL PDF"

```
PdfPCell _cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TITULO DEL PDF"));
```

Lo que necesitas solo es agregar el parrafo, sin asignarlo a una celda y listo.

```
var parrafo2 = new Paragraph("Titulo del PDF");
```

Espero haber ayudado.
Saludos!!!